# Cakephp 2.0 + Elements + requestAction = empty result

Tags: cakephp

I'm trying to use Elements in Cakephp 2.0 without luck. I have a model named Post, a controller named Posts and various views. In the layout I would like to include (for every page/view) a box with the most recent news (say 2).

So I created the element **dok-posts.ctp**

```
<?php $posts = $this->requestAction('posts/recentnews'); ?>
<?php foreach($posts as $post): ?>


<div class="Post">
....
```

In my **PostsController** I added the function **recentnews()**

```
public function recentnews(){
$posts =  $this->Post->find('all',array('order' => 'Post.created DESC','limit' => 2));
if ($this->request->is('requested')) {
    return $posts;
} else {
    $this->set('posts', $posts);
    }
}
```

In my layout, **default.ctp** I call my element

```
<?php echo $this->element('dok-posts'); ?>
```

The problem is that I get this message

```
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() [APP\View\Elements\dok-posts.ctp, line 9]
```

Debugging in **dok-posts.php**, right after the `$this->requestAction`, gives me an empty line. It seems that the `recentnews` function is not returning anything (debugging in the function returns an array with the posts found). Can anyone please tell me what am  I doing wrong?

Comment: Seems like there are still a few easy debugs to do.  Will it return a string instead of $posts?  Try a debug or 2 in your controller to find out what's going on.  Are you even getting into the first part of the if block?

Comment: Thank you. It seems that it always goes in the else branch, it never enters in the first branch.

Comment: http://mark-story.com/posts/view/reducing-requestaction-use-in-your-cakephp-sites-with-fat-models/ I'd avoid requestAction. If you have to put it in several pages, you could pass the variable to the view in the AppController or create a component.. or even use the beforeRender(), you have many options. But to request an action in the view doesn't seems too MVC to me =P

Comment: @pleasedontbelong:  That's a 2008 article that I believe is no longer relevant.  In earlier versions of CakePHP, requestActions were costly - I believe they have since been optimized a lot and are considered good practice for elements.

Comment: @Dave yeap.. but the main idea behind requestAction is still the same, even now they warn you about the performance of requestAction in the documentation page.. anyway it was just a remark, i don't see why you should make the server work harder (check the routes, check the cache, call the action, etc) just because you didn't wanted to pass the variable from the controllers.. but hey, maybe it's just me =P

Comment: @pleasedontbelong . You have raised a very interesting issue. I am a  rookie in the cakephp's world so forgive my lack of knowledge. An element is an "external" entity. I mean that a View is related to a Controller but an Element is not (at least not directly - requestAction). You wrote that I can pass a variable from the controllers. How can I set a variable in a Controller (let's say in the function **index**) and then "pass" it in an Element? Could you please give me a simple example?

Comment: @pleasedontbelong - example: An element that gets populated by the most recent 5 news articles. In your example, you'd have to repeat the code to retrieve those articles in EVERY controller action you wanted to use that element in (even if it's a one liner).  With a request action, you literally just put the element in, and voila - it works.  Completely worth it IMO.  (To each their own I suppose)

Comment: @user1496047 - just look up Element in the book - it shows how to pass parameters to elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you found out that the action is actually called,

```
$posts = $this->requestAction('posts/recentnews');
```

is working correctly. Here, for clarity and extended configuration options (for later changes to the code), I suggest you to use a Router array instead of an URL

```
$posts = $this -> requestAction(array(
 'controller' => 'posts',
 'action' => 'recentnews'
));
```

Now to your actual problem...
Since you say, it always goes into the else branch,

```
$this->request->is('requested')
```

might not work as expected. Try this (it works perfect for me):

```
if (!empty($this -> request -> params['requested'])) {
   return $posts;
}
```

Comment: Cool I could help. If this is the working solution, please "accept" it by ticking the transparent symbol below the vote counter, so it will move up and be shown to everybody who's looking for a solution to the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

In your app controller create beforefilter and getNewsElement function.

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    parent::beforeFilter();
    $data = $this->getNewsElement();
    $this->set('posts',$data);
}

function getNewsElement(){
# Put Post model in uses
$posts =  $this->Post->find('all',array('order' => 'Post.created DESC','limit' => 2));
return $posts;
}

dok-posts.ctp
#Remove <?php $posts = $this->requestAction('posts/recentnews'); ?>
<?php foreach($posts as $post): ?>

<div class="Post">
....

In  PostsController
public function recentnews(){
$posts =  $this->getNewsElement();

    $this->set('posts', $posts);

}
```

This will solve your problem!

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<?php $posts = $this->requestAction('/posts/recentnews'); ?>
```

(note the leading forward slash)

Comment: Thank you but I keep getting the same result.

Answer (score 0):

I have followed the example in the Cakephp's guide. From the moment it does not passes the if statement it seems that there is a problem with the control.

```
$this->request->is('requested')
```

So I removed the

```
is->('requested')
```

adding

```
->params['requested']
```

and it works.

Thank you all for your help (especially **wnstnsmth** for the solution).

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this

 <?php $this->requestAction('/controllerName/functionName');?>
```